# What datatype for date is using js

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Im getting car object from my Web 2 api. I create my object so can be add on the map, and include some properties. `DateTime` is type `datetime`.

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([car.X, car.Y], 'EPSG:4326',
            'EPSG:3857')),
            RoadName: car.RoadName,
            Azimuth: car.Azimuth,
            DateTime: car.DateTime
        });
```

But when check the value for the feature I get:

[image]

Im creating the info for the object, and want format the date in a readable format. What can I do?

Comment: That number looks like a 13-digit number-of-milliseconds-since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC value. You can pass that value to the [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor to get an actual `Date` object.

Comment: @Jonasw, car is an object return from one ajax call.

Comment: @nnnnnn  Where? when create the `iconFeature`? or when accessing `iconFeature.DateTIme` ??

Comment: That's up to you: it's not really clear how you want to use the value. I'd probably do it at the point where I first obtain the milliseconds value so that the rest of the app can just treat it as a `Date` object.

Comment: new Date(car.DateTime)

Comment: @RahulR. say Invalid Date :(

Comment: You need to do subsctring/regex then to get only timestamp value from DateTime.
Ideally it shouldn't be the case, if you are using correct formatting at web-api side it should be auto convertable to json. Seems something is wrong with formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS dates are shown as timestamps. To make them readable you can use the following code:

```
var minDate= -62135578800000;
var date = 
       new Date(parseInt(iconFeature.DateTime.substr(6, iconFeature.DateTime.length - 8)));

return (date.toString() == new Date(minDate).toString()) 
       ? "" 
       : (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Don't forget to upvote if you find this helpful!!

Comment: can you explain the return sentence. not sure why you need `minDate`

Comment: The minDate is the JS equivalent of the default DateTime that a property acquires in c# if no value is provided. So if we get that value then an empty string is returned else a readable date is returned. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes. But Im sure there must be an easy way to do this, because this doesnt have time, and parse every HH::MM:SS looks like too much work

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime field in the Object shown in the Image contains the timestamp value.

You can use `Date` Javascript Object to convert this into your required format. You can also perform the operations like getting next day or next hour etc. It completely depends on your requirement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Where? when create the iconFeature? or when accessing iconFeature.DateTIme ??

Comment: when accessing the iconFeature.DateTime